# Synchronization Delay Between Context Menu and Selected Row in WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, contextmenu

How can I effectively address the timing inconsistency observed in my WPF ListBox, where the selection update lags behind the display of the context menu? This issue becomes prominent when I quickly perform right-click actions on different rows. Specifically, after initiating a right-click on a row to display the context menu, there's a delay in updating the selected row. Consequently, the displayed context menu corresponds to the previously selected row rather than the row currently under the cursor. What strategies can I employ to ensure immediate synchronization between the displayed context menu and the newly selected row, even in scenarios involving rapid right-click actions on various rows?
Here the relevant part of my code:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="RowMenu" DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
        <MenuItem>
        ..
        </MenuItem>           
    </ContextMenu>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsSource}">
    <ListBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="MyViewModel.SelectedViewModel" Mode="TwoWay" />
    </ListBox.SelectedItem>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowMenu}" />
    </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MyViewModel}">
            <Grid>
               <!-- code -->
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: There is a fixed sequence of events: 1) right click on the item 2) select the clicked item 3) identify right click and open the ContextMenu 4) click on a different target (e.g. another item) 5) close the ContextMenu of the last item 6) go back to 2) The delay between each step si usually not noticeable. It coulöd become noticeable if you for example, have very complex ContextMenu definition that take long to load or you are exhausting the UI thread by doing some excessive dispatcher work in the "background".

Comment: Unless you have a very old and slow machine your posted code is guaranteed not to reproduce the issue. This code should behave perfectly (a sluggish UI is inacceptable which would disqualify WPF as a serious application framework). It's very likely that the issue is related to code that is not shown here.